# How can I change the color of the text in an editable iFrame?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an iFrame that is turned editable when the page loads, like this:

```
function iframeLoad() {
    iframe.contentDocument.designMode = 'on';
}
```

The problem is, the background of the page is very dark, and the text inside of the iFrame is black, so the user has an extremely difficult time reading the text. Is there a way to change the text color inside the iFrame to white so the user can read it? I'm making a WYSIWYG editor, and it is all in pure JS with no separate frameworks.

HTML code:

```
<div class="frame-div">
     <iframe frameborder="0" id="text-area-iframe"></iframe>
</div>
```

Also, eventually, I would like the user to have control over the text using an `<input type="color">` element. If there is a way to have the default color to be white and then have a function or method to change the color thereafter, that would be amazing.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried doing in CSS `.frame-div{color : white ;}` ?

Comment: Also, you can use `<select>` to show color options, with each one of them a different value, so that afterwards you can store that value in a variable JS (eg : blue) and style your `.frame-div` with the variable

Comment: Apply CSS style to iframes -- many answers!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe#:~:text=Style%20for%20the%20iFrame%20Section,your%20parent%20Style%20sheets%20also.

Comment: @Bob I tried using color: white, but it doesn't work

Comment: @Bob would using `<input type="color> not allow me to store the color in a variable as well? It would give the user more choices when choosing the color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you try this:

document.getElementById('text-area-iframe').contentWindow.document.body.style.color='white

Comment: Happy to help! Good luck!